# Check if mouse is inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, mouseover

I want to use an if statement to check if the mouse is inside a certain div, something like this:

```
if ( mouse is inside #element ) {
 // do something
} else {
 return;
}
```

This will result in the function to start when the mouse is inside #element, and stops when the mouse is outside #element.

Comment: Why not hook an event handler to `mouseenter`/`mouseover` for the element you need?

Comment: You could possibly do it using `getElementFromPoint()`, but hooking directly to the event on the element would be more reliable and better practice IMO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can register jQuery handlers:

```
var isOnDiv = false;
$(yourDiv).mouseenter(function(){isOnDiv=true;});
$(yourDiv).mouseleave(function(){isOnDiv=false;});
```

no jQuery alternative:

```
document.getElementById("element").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(  ) {isOnDiv=true;});
document.getElementById("element").addEventListener("mouseout", function(  ) {isOnDiv=false;});
```

and somewhereelse:

```
if ( isOnDiv===true ) {
 // do something
} else {
 return;
}
```

Comment: thanks! that is what I was looking for. Stupid that I couldn't think of that myself

Comment: This relies on the trigger of those events to go through, which isn't reliable when there are overlapping elements on the z-plane.

Comment: This will fail if another element is positioned directly over the element you are testing for.

Answer (score 22):

simply you can use this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myId");
if (element.parentNode.querySelector(":hover") == element) {
    //Mouse is inside element
} else {
    //Mouse is outside element
}
```

---

Improving using the comments

```
const element = document.getElementById("myId");
if (element.parentNode.matches(":hover")) {
    //Mouse is inside element
} else {
    //Mouse is outside element
}
```

Comment: In modern browsers you can just do `element.matches(':hover')`

Comment: Hi, clever solution.

Comment: very clever :-)

Comment: for jquery, it's `$(element).is(':hover')`

Comment: Very clever and easy solution. Worked magically

Comment: I think the second version should just be `element.matches(...)`, not `element.parentNode.matches(...)`

Answer (score 21):

Well, that's kinda of what events are for. Simply attach an event listener to the div you want to monitor.

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  // stuff to do when the mouse enters this div
}, false);
```

If you want to do it using math, you still need to have an event on a parent element or something, to be able to get the mouse coordinates, which will then be stored in an event object, which is passed to the callback.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
var divRect = document.getElementById('myDiv').getBoundingClientRect();
body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
  if (event.clientX >= divRect.left && event.clientX <= divRect.right &&
      event.clientY >= divRect.top && event.clientY <= divRect.bottom) {
      // Mouse is inside element.
    }
}, false);
```

But it's best to use the above method.

Comment: bloody hell, 10 minutes of debugging and screwing, mate!
it should be `event.clientY >= divRect.top`

Comment: lol, nope, last part should be like `event.clientY <= divRect.bottom`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_element').hover(function() {
//do something
}, function() { //else
//do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.elementFromPoint` or `document.elementsFromPoint` to get elements under mouse / finger even when those elements do not listen for events within the DOM tree.

```
const element = /* some element or window */;
element.addEventListener('pointermove', ev=>{
  const viewportX = ev.clientX
  const viewportY = ev.clientY
  // Element[]
  const hoveredElements = document.elementsFromPoint(viewportX,viewportY)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("div").mouseover(function(){
  //here your stuff so simple.. 
});
```

You can do something like this

```
var flag = false;
$("div").mouseover(function(){
    flag = true;
    testing();
});
$("div").mouseout(function(){
    flag = false;
    testing();
});

function testing(){
    if(flag){
        //mouse hover
    }else{
        //mouse out
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use it in an if statement, not like this. Thought I was quite clear in that.