# Pass mouse event to elements below HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is the [Jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/5v2xejsa/1/) demonstrating my problem

Two div tags child1 and child2 are absolutely placed, so that child2 will be on top of child1 element. I need to capture `OnMouseOut` event on child1.

I registered `OnMouseOut` event on child1, but when I hover over child2 `OnMouseOut` event is triggered even though I am still inside child1. If I put `pointer-events` as none on child2 , it works as expected. But I dont want to do this as I want to capture pointer events on child2 as well.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suspect you would probably need to get the X, Y coordinates from the "event" (ie. the parameter that is passed into the onMouseOut function, and determine if the event was triggered within the outer bounds of "child1" - if it is, then you'll obviously just ignore it

Comment: this is happening because u mouse is literary out of the element. if u wanna use absolute position u have to go with the @Craig 's comment.

Comment: @Craig I implemented the solution given here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767196/check-if-mouse-is-inside-div. But when I fastly move the mouse out of child1 area , It cannot capture it

Comment: You implemented which solution from that question?  The accepted answer, or one of the other approaches?  Ultimately, it's down to the browser interpreting the mouse movements, so if you can fly the mouse around the screen quicker than the javascript code can run, I'm not entirely sure what the answer is.  You've already seen from your own initial question that when absolute elements are stacked one on top of another, moving the mouse INTO the upper element is also counted as moving the mouse OUT of the lower element.

Comment: I tried in our jsfiddle just outputting the "offsetX" and "offsetY" values, and you're right, every once in a while I could move the mouse quick enough that the event didn't trigger.  That's not ideal, of course, but I don't know a workaround for that .....

Answer (score 1):

If you make child2 a child of child1 you can use the mouseleave event rather than the mouseout event.

> mouseleave is fired when the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants, whereas mouseout is fired when the pointer leaves the element or leaves one of the element's descendants (even if the pointer is still within the element) - [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event)

Seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5ujt4vd/4/)

```
<div id="child1">
    child1
    <div id="child2">child2</div>
</div>
//script : document.getElementById("child1").addEventListener('mouseleave',onMouseOut);
```

Comment: That is what I needed. Thank you.